# Overwriting nulls with parent data in a hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, sql-null

I have a table with the following format:

```
pk    fk     parent
===== ====== ========
001   23     000
002   null   001
003   46     001
004   12     000
005   null   004
006   null   005
=====================
```

`pk` is the primary key for each row, `fk` is a foreign key to another table I'll need to join later, and `parent` is the record's hierarchical parent. I can create a hierarchical query on this data with

```
select 
    lpad(' ',2*level)||pk "primary_key",
    fk "foreign_key",
    sys_connect_by_path(pk,'/') "path"
from example_table
connect by prior pk = parent
;
```

My question is how do I overwrite a row's `null` foreign key with that of the lowest ancestor without a null? My intended output in this scenario is

```
pk        fk   parent
========= ==== ======
001       23   000
  002     23   001
  003     46   001
004       12   000
  005     12   004
    006   12   005
====================
```

(primary keys padded to show hierarchical structure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could express this with a standard recursive common table expression:

```
with cte (pk, fk, parent, lvl, pat) as (
    select to_char(pk), fk, parent, 0, to_char(pk) from mytable where parent = 0
    union all
    select lpad(' ', 2 * (lvl + 1)) || t.pk, coalesce(t.fk, c.fk), t.parent, c.lvl + 1, c.pat || '/' || t.pk
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent = c.pk
)
select pk, fk, parent from cte order by pat
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa8ee7eecc66237ce1c51758ac9b0630)**:

```
PK    | FK | PARENT
:---- | -: | -----:
1     | 23 |      0
  2   | 23 |      1
  3   | 46 |      1
4     | 12 |      0
  5   | 12 |      4
    6 | 12 |      5
```

Comment: Very good answer, taught me a lot about rCTE's. I will note that the way you did your join tripped me up for about an hour, it might be better to have the `pk`'s in a separate column than the hierarchical view. (This is especially important if your `pk` is a `VARCHAR2` or other text data.)

Comment: I usually wait 24 hours before accepting an answer. I was actually referring to the way you used `lpad` to offset the primary keys. It works great in this example, but if the primary key is anything other than numeric data, the padding causes issues with the join.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sys_connect_by_path(fk,'/')` to aggregate parent FKs and take last one using regexp:

```sql
with example_table( pk, fk, parent) as (
select '001', 23  , '000' from dual union all
select '002', null, '001' from dual union all
select '003', 46  , '001' from dual union all
select '004', 12  , '000' from dual union all
select '005', null, '004' from dual union all
select '006', null, '005' from dual 
)
select 
    lpad(' ',2*level)||pk "primary_key",
    fk "foreign_key",
    nvl(fk, regexp_substr(sys_connect_by_path(fk,'/'),'(\d+)/*$',1,1,'',1)) fk2,
    sys_connect_by_path(pk,'/') "path"
from example_table
connect by prior pk = parent
;
```

Results:

```sql
primary_key  foreign_key        FK2 path
------------ ----------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  001                 23         23 /001
    002                          23 /001/002
    003               46         46 /001/003
  004                 12         12 /004
    005                          12 /004/005
      006                        12 /004/005/006
  002                               /002
  003                 46         46 /003
  005                               /005
    006                             /005/006
  006                               /006

11 rows selected.
```